# Odd behaviour with custom URL button

Tags: custom-button, ajax

I am trying to create a record from another object page with this custom URL button.

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT('/soap/ajax/29.0/connection.js')}

var newOpp = new sforce.SObject('Opportunity');
newOpp.AccountId = '{!Line_del__c.Linked_AccountId__c}';
newOpp.Name = '{!Line_del__c.Name}';
newOpp.StageName = 'Survey sent';
newOpp.CloseDate = new Date();

var result = sforce.connection.create([newOpp]);

if(result[0].success=='true'){
    alert('The Opportunity has been Created Successfully.');
    window.location = '/' + result[0].id;
}
```

However, I get not response, although in JavaScript console I get "Refused to set unsafe header "User-Agent"".

Quick look over forums says it might be related to cache and Chrome bug. I tried on both, latest Safari and Chrome. Tried cleaning the cache as well.

Any ideas?

**Edit**: as per suggestion, here's a more elaborate error from console:

```
[Error] Refused to set unsafe header "User-Agent"
    setRequestHeader ([native code], line 0)
    send (connection.js, line 593)
    send (connection.js, line 1012)
    _invoke (connection.js, line 1683)
    invoke (connection.js, line 1622)
    create (connection.js, line 1273)
    eval code
    eval ([native code], line 0)
    invokeAction (a0xxqbg, line 228)
    invokeOnClickJS_00xxxhvU (a0Oxxxbg, line 231)
    onclick (a0Oxxxeqbg, line 105)
```

Comment: I would alert your result variable to debug.  Could be something like a missing required fiekd.

Comment: The Error message you see is usually not a problem. If you opportunity isn't created I think you should investigate the result object and see if you can find an error message.

Comment: Can you elaborate more? The opportunity isn't created. Is there a syntax that could help capturing exception?

Comment: If your result[0].success != true print the complete result object using alert: alert("Error: " + result);  Alternatively add debugger; and chrome should stop execution and you should be able to investigate the contents of the variable I. The chrome developer tools.